# HTML Helper is always null in DNN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke

When i use `@Html.Raw("<H1>Hello</H1>");`

I got error

The best overloaded method match for 'DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.Helpers.HtmlHelper.Raw(string)' has some invalid arguments

[image]

Comment: show the exception, what is the invalid argument

Answer (score 1):

You pass a `dynamic` Object into `Html.Raw`. But `Html.Raw` take `string` type parameter. So change your code like:

```
 var onlineSeminarsCatagoty= _service.GetData();//Your value
```

OR

```
 YourModel onlineSeminarsCatagoty= _service.GetData();//Your value
```

then

```
@html.Raw(onlineSeminarsCatagoty.Description)
```

**UPDATE**

sometime razor engine can't point out exact position where exception came from.
I thing your exception come form bellow `Html.Raw` maybe `renderpage` section.
so  try to use full path inside `renderpage` like `@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/SamplePage.cshtml")` or use `RenderPartial` rather than `renderpage` example `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_YourPage"); }`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help the null exception comes from @html.Raw() not from the data because when i write @Html.Raw("<p>Hi</p>") i still get the  null exception